Complex XPath in XML columns in a SQL Server table
I have a table, containing an XML column XmlMsg. This column can contain orderstatus, vehiclestatus, ....
I am interested only in orderstatus nodes, and more exactly in the following two cases:

The last orderpart is "Pending".
The last orderpart is "Pending" and the last but one is "Completed".

An example of the first one is the following (only showing the relevant part):
<orderstatus responsecode="0"
             ...
             numberoforderparts="3">
    ...
    <orderparts>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="1"/>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="2"/>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="3">
            <eventtype>Pending</eventtype>
            ...
        </orderpart>
    </orderparts>
</orderstatus>

An example of the second one is the following (also only showing the relevant part):
<orderstatus responsecode="0"
             ...
             numberoforderparts="3">
    ...
    <orderparts>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="1"/>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="2">
            <eventtype>Completed</eventtype>
            ...
        </orderpart>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="3">
            <eventtype>Pending</eventtype>
            ...
        </orderpart>
    </orderparts>
</orderstatus>

I am able getting the first list with this query:
SELECT *,
    XmlMsg.value('(/orderstatus/@numberoforderparts)[1]', 'INT') AS NumberOfOrderParts,
    
    -- Retrieve the last orderpart with eventtype="Pending"
    XmlMsg.query('(/orderstatus/orderparts/orderpart[@orderpartnumber = (/orderstatus/@numberoforderparts)[1] and eventtype="Pending"])[1]') AS LastOrderPart,
    
    -- Retrieve the second-to-last orderpart with eventtype="Completed"
    XmlMsg.query('(/orderstatus/orderparts/orderpart[@orderpartnumber = (/orderstatus/@numberoforderparts)[1] - 1 and eventtype="Completed"])[1]') AS PreviousOrderPart
FROM 
    [dbo].[AWIMessageLogs]
WHERE 
    Source = 'RCV_RESP' 
    AND LogDateTime >= '2024-11-26' 
    AND LogDateTime <= '2024-11-26 15:00' 
    AND XmlMsg.exist('/orderstatus') = 1
    -- Ensure that the last orderpart has eventtype="Pending"
    AND XmlMsg.query('(/orderstatus/orderparts/orderpart[@orderpartnumber = (/orderstatus/@numberoforderparts)[1] and eventtype="Pending"])[1]') IS NOT NULL

However, I have no idea how to get the second list.
Does anybody have an idea?

Wouldn't the "last one is pending" make your second condition (about complete) redundant? Or do you want to actually fetch those rows

@siggemannen: I'm looking for both lists: one where the last one is pending and another list where the last one is complete but the last but one is pending. I already have found the SQL query for the first list, and now I'm looking for the SQL query for the second list.


The last orderpart is "Pending".

orderstatus[orderparts/orderpart[last()]/eventtype='Pending']


The last orderpart is "Pending" and the last but one is "Complete".

orderstatus[orderparts/orderpart[last()]/eventtype='Pending' and
            orderparts/orderpart[last()-1]/eventtype='Completed']


I'm sorry, but I have put all "orderstatus" nodes in a "List", and when I launch the XPath expression /List/orderstatus[orderparts/orderpart[last()-1]/eventtype='Complete'], I don't get any results.

Then it's failing because of something you haven't told us about. Namespaces perhaps?

I really feel like a fool now: it's not "Complete" but "Completed" :-) Just another question: when launching that XPath in Notepad++ XML Plugin, I see the "orderstatus" (which is the name), but the value is empty. Do you know what I can modify in order to see the value being filled in?

@Dominique Be careful if an orderstatus can contain multiple orderparts, as this solution doesn't enforce orderpart[last()] to share the same parent as orderpart[last()-1]. Though it might be want you want.

@Fravadona: ??? I am looking for the orderstatus instances, containing a bunch of orderpart instances, the latter need to obey the following conditions: the last one needs to be "Pending" and the last but one needs to be "Completed" (both at the same time). I thought that was clear. What do you mean by "no enforce to share the same parent"?

@Dominique This one will give a "false-positive" with the second expression: <orderstatus><orderparts><orderpart><eventtype>Pending</eventtype></orderpart></orderparts><orderparts><orderpart><eventtype>Complete</eventtype></orderpart><orderpart><eventtype>Whatever</eventtype></orderpart></orderparts></orderstatus>

@Fravadona: Oops, that's indeed not clear in my question: every orderstatus contains at most one orderpart**s**, which, at its turn, can contain a list of single orderpart instances, so your example is impossible and should be replaced by <orderstatus>orderparts><orderpart Nbr="1"><eventtype>Pending</eventtype></orderpart><orderpart Nbr="2"><eventtype>Complete</eventtype></orderpart><orderpart Nbr="3"><eventtype>Whatever</eventtype></orderpart></orderparts></orderstatus>, how would the query react on this?

@Fravadona: sorry for asking. I've executed the query and it works fine.

@Dominique Then it doesn't matter indeed. I pointed it out because Mike is very picky with the full exactness of the answers.

@Fravadona: ... that's the attitude we are all looking for :-) Thanks a lot, Fravadona and Michael, for all the help.

This stuff is usually easier to get by using nodes method, something like:
CREATE TABLE #xml (x xml, id int IDENTITY)

INSERT INTO #xml VALUES(N'<orderstatus responsecode="0"
             numberoforderparts="3">
    
    <orderparts>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="1"/>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="2"/>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="3">
            <eventtype>Pending</eventtype>
        </orderpart>
    </orderparts>
</orderstatus>'), ('<orderstatus responsecode="0"
             numberoforderparts="3">
    <orderparts>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="1"/>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="2">
            <eventtype>Complete</eventtype>
        </orderpart>
        <orderpart orderpartnumber="3">
            <eventtype>Pending</eventtype>
        </orderpart>
    </orderparts>
</orderstatus>')

SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   CASE 
            WHEN orderpart = max(orderpart) OVER(partition BY id) AND eventtype = 'Pending' -- Last pending
            OR (
                orderpart = max(orderpart) OVER(partition BY id) -1 AND eventtype = 'Complete' -- Complete and last is pending
                AND LEAD(eventtype) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY orderpart) = 'Pending'
            )
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
    
    FROM    (
        SELECT  op.value('@orderpartnumber', 'int') AS orderpart, et.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS eventtype
        ,   id
        FROM    #xml t
        CROSS apply x.nodes(N'orderstatus/orderparts/orderpart') t1(op)
        OUTER apply op.nodes(N'eventtype') t2(et)
        ) x
    ) x
WHERE   flag = 1

Then you can either use some LAG/LEAD to lookup the relevant values or put data into a temp table and process it from there.
Output:



orderpart
eventtype
id
flag




3
Pending
1
1


2
Complete
2
1


3
Pending
2
1




Thanks for the elaborated answer but I never worked with so-called nodes before and it seems not straightforward. I'm looking for other means to solve my issue.

You can use XPath 1.0 for both queries:

Get the orderstatus nodes where the last orderpart is "Pending":
//orderstatus[
    orderparts/orderpart[last()]/eventtype = "Pending"
]


Get the orderstatus nodes where the last orderpart is "Pending" and the penultimate is "Complete":
//orderstatus[
    orderparts[
        orderpart[last()]/eventtype = "Pending" and
        orderpart[last()-1]/eventtype = "Complete"
    ]
]



db<>fiddle (by @Charlieface)
